# How To Read Multiple Sensors At One Time

Tags: python-3.x, class, raspberry-pi3, sensors

I have a raspberry pi and five sensors; three are waterproof temperature sensors and the other two are humidity/temperature sensors. What is the best way to read all sensors at one time and to store their data in text files? I am using python3 and I already have code storing individual sensor readings in text files but as of right now, I have to run different scripts for each sensor. I want to combine the five different scripts into one script. Would a module with three classed be used for this? For instance, one class being used to acquire the waterproof temperature data, another class to acquire the humidity sensor data, and one last class to write the data to the text files? This is very novice of me to ask but just so I do not catch the wrath of stack exchange, I am a mechanical engineer by degree but my current position is an embedded systems engineer. The only other guy that works with me is very experienced programmer and is extremely condescending when he explain things so it is hard for me to learn simply by analyzing his code so that is why I came here. I hope you understand and I will be very thankful for help.

Answer (score 0):

You could either read one sensor then the other in a loop. I'm not sure what the code for reading data looks like but I would imagine that may be possible. If not you will have to use a multi threaded system (https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html).

Having multiple threads means that you have multiple blocks of code running at the same time, this bring in some complications but it shouldn't be too hard to just have 2 threads running at the same time. Hope that helps, good luck with your project.

Also if you could write a bash script to start all 5 scripts at once like so:

```
python3 script1.py &
python3 script2.py &
python3 script3.py &
```

and then run that file to start all at once.

Answer (score 0):

i made some project with rpi4 using MQ135(gas sensor) FC-28(soil sensor) and ldr sensor. you may try to this links[run multiple sensor in one script](https://github.com/sredeck/project)